# How to get value from barcode static image?

Tags: ios, swift, barcode

I want to get the value from the static barcode image.

Currently I am scanning barcode through camera live session, but now I want to get the value from static barcode image.

I am using Swift programming language.

```
QRcode static image code :

let qrcodeImg = QRCodeImageField.image

        let detector:CIDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeQRCode, context: nil, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh])!
        let ciImage:CIImage=CIImage(image:qrcodeImg!)!
        var qrCodeLink=""

        let features=detector.features(in: ciImage)
        for feature in features as! [CIQRCodeFeature] {
            qrCodeLink += feature.messageString!
        }

        if qrCodeLink=="" {
            print("nothing")
        }else{
            print("message: \(qrCodeLink)")
        }

Barcode scanner live camera session code :
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        if metadataObjects.count != 0
        {
            if let object = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
            {
                if object.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code128
                    //if supportedCodeTypes.contains(metadataObj.type)
                {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Bar CODE", message: object.stringValue, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Retake", style: .default, handler: nil))
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Copy", style: .default, handler: {(nil) in UIPasteboard.general.string = object.stringValue
                        self.barCode_Generation(barCodeString: object.stringValue!)
                    }))
                    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No sir. The answer is related to QR code only and I am asking about barcode.

Comment: What is the issue exactly? Can't you separate the code that is analyzing the image from the code related to the camera, and use it for both input methods, for example? Please explain your issue with more details.

Comment: I simply need a method to which I provided the barcode image and in return it provides me with the barcode value. Barcode scanner using live camera is done now I need to do it with static images.

Comment: What about the solution I gave in my comment? The real question is: why don't you do that, or any other logical refactoring of your code? Because you *already* have a solution for analyzing a barcode. Your issue is not an issue, it's just that you need to make your existing solution available for different inputs (camera *and* static image). Am I right? :)

Comment: The solution you provided is entirely different from my scenario. Scanning the barcode and qrcode from live camera session and getting value from qrcode static image is also done. Now I am searching for the solution for the static barcode images.

Comment: @saifwasif Have you get any answer?

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD no dear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MLKit for that

Install below Pod

```
pod 'GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning', '3.2.0'
```

Don't forget to import

```
import MLKit
import MLKitBarcodeScanning
```

Use below function

```
func scanBarcode(fromImage: UIImage) {
        let barcodeOptions = BarcodeScannerOptions(formats: .all)
        
        // To scan barcode from image pass image
        let image = VisionImage(image: fromImage)
        // Create Barcode scanner object
        let barcodeScanner = BarcodeScanner.barcodeScanner()
        
        // Process the image
        barcodeScanner.process(image) { features, error in
            guard error == nil, let features = features, !features.isEmpty else {
                // Error handling
                print("Unexpected error occured")
                return
              }
              // Recognized barcodes
            print("Barcodes Array = \(features)")
            for barcode in features {
                print("Barcode Value = \(barcode.displayValue ?? "")")
                let corners = barcode.cornerPoints
                
                let displayValue = barcode.displayValue
                let rawValue = barcode.rawValue
                
                let valueType = barcode.valueType
                switch valueType {
                case .wiFi:
                    let ssid = barcode.wifi?.ssid
                    let password = barcode.wifi?.password
                    let encryptionType = barcode.wifi?.type
                case .URL:
                    let title = barcode.url!.title
                    let url = barcode.url!.url
                default: break
                    // See API reference for all supported value types
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Happy Coding !!